# Directory is not writable CentOS7, Apache 2.4.6, PHP 5.4.16

Tags: php, apache

I have Linux user, let say **admin**. Apache process is running under **admin** user. I have the next simple script for testing permissions:

```
<?php
$flag=is_writable("/var/www/html/admin/protected/runtime");
if($flag)
  print "Is writable\n";
else
  print "Is not writable\n";

echo 'Current user: ' . exec('whoami');
?>
```

When I run this script in the **console** it says:

```
Is writable
Current user: admin
```

When I open page in the **Firefox** it says:

```
Is not writable Current user: admin
```

I'm confused, how it can be that directory is writable and is not writable simultaneously under the same user?

Comment: Can you output the result of `ini_get('open_basedir');` (can be the problem). Also (if you have shell root acces to that server): run `setenforce 0` and run your script again to verify whether selinux is the problem.

Comment: 1. ini_get('open_basedir'); is empty. 2. I have changed enforcement mode to permissive - did not help.

Comment: I found interesting thing that /var/tmp directory is writable in both cases, but if I create /var/tmp/runtime directory - the same problem appears.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, `setenforce 0` has solved my problem, I have recreated directory after setting enforcement mode to permissive and this directory is writable in both cases. But is it right solution?

Comment: Actually no. Enforcment mode is used on check-time, and setting it to permissive mode is the easiest way to verify that selinux was blocking a read/write. Perhaps by recreating the folder their were now other user/group-permission set than the first time. Do I understand correctly that the problem is solved for now?

Comment: Yes, problem is solved. User/Group is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in selinux. Permissive mode `setenforce 0` - solves problem. But it is not good solution, better one is configure selinux. More about selinux available here https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

See https://techblog.jeppson.org/2016/10/install-wordpress-centos-7/ which answered a lot of my SELinux issues.

Basically you can leave `setenforce` to `1` and run

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/
sudo restorecon -v /var/www/html/
```

to grant specific permissions to your wordpress directory.

==== EDIT ====

In practice, it worked to solve the top wordpress root directory issue but lower levels have an issue. I ended up with:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sure that centos is viewing your browser as a non group user, therefore if your permissions for that directory are anything but 777, Firefoxe probably won't be able to do it.

you could change ownership of the directory to apache with
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path-to-directory

or you could try making the file permissions 777 just to see if that is the problem.

In general, it is best to save files to your database for security reasons.